# Derivative of sigmoid

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, calculus

I'm creating a neural network using the backpropagation technique for learning.

I understand we need to find the derivative of the activation function used. I'm using the standard sigmoid function

```
f(x) = 1 / (1 + e^(-x))
```

and I've seen that its derivative is

```
dy/dx = f(x)' = f(x) * (1 - f(x))
```

This may be a daft question, but does this mean that we have to pass x through the sigmoid function twice during the equation, so it would expand to

```
dy/dx = f(x)' = 1 / (1 + e^(-x)) * (1 - (1 / (1 + e^(-x))))
```

or is it simply a matter of taking the already calculated output of `f(x)`, which is the output of the neuron, and replace that value for `f(x)`?

Comment: I would suggest trying to take the derivative yourself. With a bit of algebra you can derive exactly f(x) * (1 - f(x)), and then you'll understand exactly what is going on. (And the answer below are 100% correct.)

Comment: think of your original problem in terms of substitution and you'll see that f(x) is a common term you can factor out via substitution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two ways of doing it are equivalent (since mathematical functions don't have side-effects and always return the same input for a given output), so you might as well do it the (faster) second way.

Answer (score 46):

Dougal is correct. Just do

```
f = 1/(1+exp(-x))
df = f * (1 - f)
```

Answer (score 6):

A little algebra can simplify this so that you don't have to have df call f.
    df = exp(-x)/(1+exp(-x))^2

derivation:

```
df = 1/(1+e^-x) * (1 - (1/(1+e^-x)))
df = 1/(1+e^-x) * (1+e^-x - 1)/(1+e^-x)
df = 1/(1+e^-x) * (e^-x)/(1+e^-x)
df = (e^-x)/(1+e^-x)^2
```

Comment: i would put explanation in comment and just have a single line function returning derived value (as you have calculated in last line)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the output of your `sigmoid` function and pass it to your `SigmoidDerivative` function to be used as the `f(x)` in the following:

```
dy/dx = f(x)' = f(x) * (1 - f(x))
```